# Using gsub or sub function to only get part of a string?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

```
      Col
WBU-ARGU*06:03:04
WBU-ARDU*08:01:01
WBU-ARFU*11:03:05
WBU-ARFU*03:456
```

I have a column which has 75 rows of variables such as the col above. I am not quite sure how to use gsub or sub in order to get up until the integers after the first colon.

Expected output:

```
      Col
WBU-ARGU*06:03
WBU-ARDU*08:01
WBU-ARFU*11:03
WBU-ARFU*03:456
```

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
gsub("*..:","", df$col)
```

Comment: `col` or `Col`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following may help you here too.

```
sub("([^:]*):([^:]*).*","\\1:\\2",df$dat)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
> sub("([^:]*):([^:]*).*","\\1:\\2",df$dat)
[1] "WBU-ARGU*06:03"   "WBU-ARDU*08:01"   "WBU-ARFU*11:03"   "WBU-ARFU*03:456b"
```

Where Input for data frame is as follows.

```
dat <- c("WBU-ARGU*06:03:04","WBU-ARDU*08:01:01","WBU-ARFU*11:03:05","WBU-ARFU*03:456b")
df <- data.frame(dat)
```

***Explanation:*** Following is only for explanation purposes.

```
sub("      ##using sub for global subtitution function of R here.
([^:]*)     ##By mentioning () we are keeping the matched values from vector's element into 1st place of memory(which we could use later), which is till next colon comes it will match everything.
:           ##Mentioning letter colon(:) here.
([^:]*)     ##By mentioning () making 2nd place in memory for matched values in vector's values which is till next colon comes it will match everything.
.*"         ##Mentioning .* to match everything else now after 2nd colon comes in value.
,"\\1:\\2"  ##Now mentioning the values of memory holds with whom we want to substitute the element values \\1 means 1st memory place \\2 is second memory place's value.
,df$dat)    ##Mentioning df$dat dataframe's dat value.
```

Comment: this worked but it didn't include the ":". For the first one WBU-ARGU*06:03:04 it outputs WBU-ARGU*0603. How do I make it WBU-ARGU*06:03?

Comment: @nathan, but when I am checking I could see it is working fine only `> gsub("([^:]*):([^:]*).*","\\1:\\2",df$dat)
[1] "WBU-ARGU*06:03"   "WBU-ARDU*08:01"   "WBU-ARFU*11:03"   "WBU-ARFU*03:456b"`

Comment: I missed the colon in "\\1:\\2", works fine now thank you!

Comment: You do not need a `gsub`, a `sub` is enough since you only need to match and replace once in each character vector.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
df$col <- sub("(\\d:\\d+):\\d+$", "\\1", df$col)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AKafJF/3)

**Details**

- `(\\d:\\d+)` - Capturing group 1 (its value will be accessible via `\1` in the replacement pattern): a digit, a colon and 1+ digits.
- `:` - a colon
- `\\d+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

[R Demo](https://ideone.com/nQjbC4):

```
col <- c("WBU-ARGU*06:03:04","WBU-ARDU*08:01:01","WBU-ARFU*11:03:05","WBU-ARFU*03:456")
sub("(\\d:\\d+):\\d+$", "\\1", col)
## => [1] "WBU-ARGU*06:03"  "WBU-ARDU*08:01"  "WBU-ARFU*11:03"  "WBU-ARFU*03:456"
```

**Alternative approach**:

```
df$col <- sub("^(.*?:\\d+).*", "\\1", df$col)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yGSVhy/1)

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?:\\d+)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible (due to the lazy `*?` quantifier), then `:` and 1+ digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

However, it should be used with the PCRE regex engine, pass `perl=TRUE`:

```
col <- c("WBU-ARGU*06:03:04","WBU-ARDU*08:01:01","WBU-ARFU*11:03:05","WBU-ARFU*03:456")
sub("^(.*?:\\d+).*", "\\1", col, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "WBU-ARGU*06:03"  "WBU-ARDU*08:01"  "WBU-ARFU*11:03"  "WBU-ARFU*03:456"
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/uHKoYB).

Comment: Thank you for the demo, that was really helpful as well!

Comment: @nathan I added another solution that basically follows your logic: grabs the substring from start till the first `:` followed with 1+ digits, and removes the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub("(\\d+:\\d+):\\d+$", "\\1", df$Col)
[1] "WBU-ARGU*06:03"  "WBU-ARDU*08:01"  "WBU-ARFU*11:03"  "WBU-ARFU*03:456"
```

Alternatively match what you want (instead of subbing out what you don't want) with `stringi`:

```
stringi::stri_extract_first(df$Col, regex = "[A-Z-\\*]+\\d+:\\d+")
```

Slightly more concise `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_extract(df$Col, "[A-Z-\\*]+\\d+:\\d+")
# or
stringr::str_extract(df$Col, "[\\w-*]+\\d+:\\d+")
```